# Change ion icon color dynamically on like/dislike

Tags: angular, object, ionic-framework

Im having problems changing the color of the icon upon liking or disliking the project.  What seems to be my problem on my ngIf?
HTML

```
 <ion-icon *ngIf="!project.likedBy" color="dark" name="heart">
 </ion-icon>

 <ion-icon *ngIf="project.likedBy" color="danger" name="heart">
 </ion-icon>
 <span>{{project.numLikes}}</span>
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For dynamically changing color you don't really require to create 2 icons. You can write expression to dynamically change color like shown below.

```
<ion-icon [color]="project.likedBy ? 'danger' : 'dark'" name="heart">
```

Also make sure that the likedBy property is a boolean value. Else you might have to adjust the condition to set the color string.

Comment: How do I provide `rgb` colors such as `rgb(255,204,0)` to this. More specifically values bound to a slider data model. I tried  `<ion-icon [color]="sessionScore < 5 ? '+sessionColor+' : 'white'" ios="ios-sad-outline" md="md-sad"></ion-icon>` where `sessionColor = rgb(255,204,0);` or similar value...

Comment: You can try putting dynamic class style with color attribute. [ngClass]="getClassName()" then you can write to return class name according to your logic from ts file and apply style according to it

.ios_color {
  color:rgb(255,204,0);
}
.android_color {
color:rgb(255,204,101);
}

Answer (score 1):

```
***In Typescript***

if(favourite) {
            x.FavouriteImg = 'danger';
          } else {
            x.FavouriteImg = 'dark';
          }
    enter code here

**In design page**

 <ion-icon [color]="item.FavouriteImg" name="heart" slot="end"></ion-icon>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.